# If we dock the mobile device to a PC via USB, will we be able to get a network connection directly from the USB connection?

Tags: windows-mobile, synchronization

if we dock the mobile device to a PC via USB, do we need to use ActiveSync to do the data syncing? Or will we be able to get a network connection directly from the USB connection.

Comment: Does not appear to be programming related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  ActiveSync can be configured to allow "pass through" networking, but it can also be disabled.  Some devices (like my HD2) can also change the connection behavior and you can choose not to use ActiveSync.